# Cygwin debugging error.

Tags: windows, debugging, cygwin

I have an executable built in Windows. I want to pass that .exe to an output file built by Cygwin (DOS version). It is going well up to a point, after which it is showing the following error related to Cygwin dll files (ACL check) .

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x6108829e in cygwin1!aclcheck () from /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll
(gdb)
```

Why am I getting this error and where should I look?

Comment: try a cygwin forum/board. I'm not trying to put you off, but this is not a programming question, and look like not even your app... it's the underlying platform.

Comment: Please rephrase.
What do you mean by "passing exe to an out file"? Do you mean redirecting?
Also, what is "Cygwin(DOS version)"? As far as I know Cygwin is windows only. (hence the win)

Answer (score 0):

Check your code. Since you're already using gdb, `bt full` shall be your friend. You're possibly passing bad parameters such as invalid pointers to some system call.

It's likely it's not `aclcheck` where the segfault itself occurs. Cygwin DLLs are normally not shipped with debugging symbols built in. gdb works backwards from the instruction pointer and takes the previous symbol seen. In non-debug builds there are only symbols of exported functions.